# MongoDB unknown top level operator

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Well I'm having problems with aggragate of the mongo, I need to validate if in all the answers it doesn't have a field marked as deletedAt. My aggragate looks like this:

```
[
    { '$match': { _id: "5f0cc0e676de351ce21a752b" } },
    {
        '$lookup': {
            from: 'Exams',
            localField: 'exams.idExams',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'exams'
        }
    },
    {
        '$lookup': {
            from: 'Sports',
            localField: 'idSports',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'sportPracticed'
        }
    },
    {
        '$unwind': { path: '$sportPracticed', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }
    },
    {
        '$lookup': {
            from: 'Galery',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'idPlayer',
            as: 'galery'
        }
    },
    {
        '$lookup': {
            from: 'EvaluationPlayer',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'idPlayer',
            as: 'evaluationPlayer'
        }
    },
    {
        '$lookup': {
            from: 'Evaluation',
            localField: 'evaluationPlayer.idEvaluation',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'evaluations'
        }
    },
    {
        '$lookup': {
            from: 'Category',
            localField: 'evaluations.idCategory',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'category'
        }
    },
    {
        '$lookup': {
            from: 'Club',
            localField: 'idClub',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'club'
        }
    },
    { '$unwind': { path: '$club', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
    {
        '$lookup': {
            from: 'Agent',
            localField: 'idAgent',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'agent'
        }
    },
    { '$unwind': { path: '$agent', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
    {
        $match: {
            $and: [
                { $exams: { $elemMatch: { deletedAt: { $exists: false } } } },
                { $sportPracticed: { deletedAt: { $exists: false } } },
                { $galery: { $elemMatch: { deletedAt: { $exists: false } } } },
                { $evaluationPlayer: { $elemMatch: { deletedAt: { $exists: false } } } },
                { $evaluations: { $elemMatch: { deletedAt: { $exists: false } } } },
                { $category: { $elemMatch: { deletedAt: { $exists: false } } } },
                { $club: { deletedAt: { $exists: false } } },
                { $agent: { deletedAt: { $exists: false } } },
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

However, when this code is executed, it returns the error: `unknown top level operator: $ exams`.

How can I solve this problem ?

My plans is not to bring data from relationships where it has already been deleted and what says that it was deleted is the existence of the `deleteadAt`;

Collection Player:

```
[{
  "_id": "5f0cc0e676de351ce21a752b",
  "language": "pt-br",
  "country": "BR",
  "status": true,
  "name": "Laura Silva",
  "nickname": "laurasilva",
  "dateOfBirth": "1995-05-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "email": "laurasilva@gmail.com",
  "phones": [],
  "cpf": "54721452365",
  "gender": "F",
  "father": "Luiz Silva",
  "mother": "Larissa Silva",
  "weight": "67",
  "height": "1.67",
  "currentTeam": {
    "name": "América",
    "initialDate": "2020-01-01"
  },
  "professionalPlayer": true,
  "bird": "ARW1",
  "idSports": "5f0cbe10e6c0930b8dcc5181",
  "competitions": [],
  "exams": [],
  "preference": [],
  "coachReferrals": [],
  "createdAt": "2020-07-13T20:15:34.348Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-07-13T20:15:34.348Z",
  "__v": 0,
  "idAgent": null,
  "idClub": null
},
{
  "_id": "5ee644c0280583764bfe7d97",
  "currentTeam": {
    "name": "Cruzeiro",
    "initialDate": "2019-02-25"
  },
  "network": {
    "instagram": {
      "url": "@renanmoaesoficial"
    }
  },
  "language": "pt-br",
  "country": "BR",
  "status": true,
  "name": "Renan Moraes",
  "nickname": "renanmoraes",
  "dateOfBirth": "1993-01-21T00:00:00.000Z",
  "email": "renan.desenvolviemnto@gmail.com",
  "phones": [
    {
      "_id": "5ee644c0280583764bfe7d98",
      "phone": "(31) 98796-1357"
    }
  ],
  "cpf": "123.367.952-85",
  "gender": "M",
  "father": "Antonio",
  "mother": "Sandra",
  "weight": "1,80",
  "height": "45",
  "professionalPlayer": false,
  "bird": "2551566655",
  "idSports": "5ee640d040b0a0649799c531",
  "exams": [
    {
      "results": [],
      "attestation": [],
      "_id": "5ee644c0280583764bfe7d9a",
      "idExams": "5ee6405f061a1362c3778435"
    },
    {
      "results": [],
      "attestation": [],
      "_id": "5ee644c0280583764bfe7d99",
      "idExams": "5ee6406e061a1362c3778436"
    }
  ],
  "standardPhoto": "https://exame.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/capaprofile.jpg?quality=70&strip=info",
  "competitions": [],
  "preference": [],
  "coachReferrals": [],
  "createdAt": "2020-06-14T15:39:44.198Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-06-14T15:39:44.198Z",
  "__v": 0,
  "idAgent": null,
  "idClub": "5f176c8d58beb94efe56c59b"
}]
```

Collection medicalExams:

```
{
  "_id": "5ee6406e061a1362c3778436",
  "status": true,
  "name": "Exames das prostatas",
  "value": "1",
  "type": "A",
  "createdAt": "2020-06-14T15:21:18.114Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-06-14T15:21:18.114Z",
  "__v": 0
},
{
  "_id": "5ee6405f061a1362c3778435",
  "status": true,
  "name": "Exames dos rins",
  "value": "3",
  "type": "M",
  "createdAt": "2020-06-14T15:21:03.405Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-06-14T15:21:03.405Z",
  "__v": 0
}
```

Here on this site there is an example of the error, in which case the two items would need to come ... https://mongoplayground.net/p/IgnIt8wGvKq

Comment: Don't use `$` in `$exams` and other fields as well `$sportPracticed`... when you $match. check here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/,

Comment: @viagem maybe the problem is when you have the other matchs

Comment: try to simulate all relationships, even returning empty. Because in my case it doesn't work when it does, it has relationships that don't return values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I managed to solve my problem .. It turns out that I needed to make a pipeline for each existing lookup relationship, careful that I was looking for the data in the correct way.

I had relationships that were made in an array, and I needed to match each item in my array with an id from another collection. And to achieve this I added let to declare variables to be used within my lookup and then use $ in to do specific searches for those ids ..

Anyway the final object was like this, I took some items that were also not important to make it simpler.

```
{
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Exams",
      "let": {
        "exams_items": "$exams.idExams"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$in": [
                "$_id",
                "$$exams_items"
              ]
            },
            "deletedAt": {
              $exists: false
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "allExams"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Sports",
      "let": {
        "id_sport": "$idSports"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$eq": [
                "$_id",
                "$$id_sport"
              ]
            },
            "deletedAt": {
              $exists: false
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "sportPracticed"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      "path": "$sportPracticed",
      "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Galery",
      "let": {
        "id_player": "$_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$eq": [
                "$idPlayer",
                "$$id_player"
              ]
            },
            "deletedAt": {
              $exists: false
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "galery"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "EvaluationPlayer",
      "let": {
        "id_player": "$_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$eq": [
                "$idPlayer",
                "$$id_player"
              ]
            },
            "deletedAt": {
              $exists: false
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "evaluationPlayer"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Club",
      localField: "idClub",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "club"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      "path": "$club",
      "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Agent",
      localField: "idAgent",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "agent"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      "path": "$agent",
      "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
    }
  }
```

Comment: Glad that you got it fixed ;)

Answer (score 6):

Key references in `$match` stage shouldn't begin with `$` sign.

Remove `$` sign from the `$match` stage.

Also, the `deletedAt`key for last two conditions should not be in separate parenthesis.

```
{
        $match: {
            $and: [
                { exams: { $elemMatch: { deletedAt: { $exists: false } } } },
                { galery: { $elemMatch: { deletedAt: { $exists: false } } } },
                { evaluationPlayer: { $elemMatch: { deletedAt: { $exists: false } } } },
                { evaluations: { $elemMatch: { deletedAt: { $exists: false } } } },
                { category: { $elemMatch: { deletedAt: { $exists: false } } } },
                { "sportPracticed.deletedAt": { $exists: false } },
                { "club.deletedAt": { $exists: false } },
                { "agent.deletedAt": { $exists: false } },
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because what I see is in the aggregations he does not bring the items .. Example I have the gallery, if there is no item it must return an empty array ... And it is not being done like this, you know what it can be?

Comment: oK, await moment

Comment: I updated the question, add a base example. In case I do a findAll it should return all of me with including relationships.

Comment: Here on this site there is an example of the error, in which case the two items would need to come ... https://mongoplayground.net/p/IgnIt8wGvKq